# Внесение данных в Treeview и их непосредственное обновление в окне Tkinter

Tags: python, функции, list, tkinter, treeview

Я знаю, что сюда нужно писать конкретные вопросы и желательно, чтобы они были полезны сообществу.
Я только учусь и хочу улучшать понимание Python.
У меня есть рабочий кусок кода. Он не работал, но я самостоятельно смог заставить его работать, но...
Я хотел бы узнать у знающих людей, как можно его улучшить - сделать более правильным. Мне кажется, он сделан не рационально с точки зрения программирования.
Есть функция:

```
def add():
    for contact in lst.get_children():
         tree_profile.delete(contact)
    for contact in lst: 
         tree_profile.insert("", tk.END, values=contact)
```

**Её цель** - при нажатии на кнопку добавлять в список новые значения, а затем обновлять **Treeview**, чтобы пользователь мог сразу посмотреть таблицу с вновь добавленными к ней значениями.
Реализовал я это через два цикла - сначала удаляю все значения из **Treeview**, а потом через цикл заполняю по новой из списка + новые значения.
Без этапа удаления, при дополнении новых значений, у меня повторяются предыдущие и тем самым создаются дубликаты в таблице.
Ребята, я понимаю - что удаление таблицы и заполнение её заново не столь рационально. Подскажите, в какую сторону двигаться, что почитать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437232/widget-in-sub-window-update-with-real-time-data-in-tkinter-python

Comment: Большое спасибо, не наткнулся видимо. Ознакомлюсь =)